# Prove that $F_{m}$ is continuous.

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, cauchy-integral-formula

I'm trying to verify that $F_{m}$ it is more continuous, but I'm not getting it. I've tried using Newton's Binomial, but it did not..

*Let $\lambda$ be a rectifiable curve and suppose $\phi$ is a function defined and continuos on {$\lambda$}. For each $m\geq 1$ let $F_{m}(z)=\int_\lambda \! \phi(w)(w-z)^{-m} \, \mathrm{d}w$. Then each $F_{m}$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C}$ $-$ ${\lambda}$ and $F_{m}′(z)=mF_{m+1}(z)$.*  (Conway, Lemma 5.1, pg. 83 (second edition))

Comment: Do you know how to go on after the continuity is established?

Comment: Yes, I can. It seems to be simple continuity, but I can not do it.

Comment: Invoke a theorem about the continuity of parameter-dependent integrals. If you know a little Lebesgue theory, you can use the dominated convergence theorem. There's also a suitable theorem for Riemann integrals, though I don't recall the name. Note that $g_m(w,z) = \frac{\phi(w)}{(w-z)^m}$ is a continuous function on $\lambda \times (\mathbb{C}\setminus \lambda)$.